# Extract header names from a CSV and use it to plot against each other in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am pretty new to python and coding in general. I have this code so far.

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

mSec = data[:,0]
Airspeed = data[:,10]
AS_Cmd = data[:,25]
airspeed = data[:,3]

plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=25) #increase xaxis tick size
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=25) #increase yaxis tick size

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,40), edgecolor='b')
ax.patch.set_facecolor('white')


ax.plot(mSec, Airspeed, label='Ground speed [m/s]')
ax.plot(mSec, AS_Cmd, label='Voltage [V]')

plt.legend(loc='best',prop={'size':20})
fig.savefig('trans2.png', dpi=(200), bbox_inches='tight') #borderless on save
```

However, I don't want to individually read every data column there is. I want to be able to load a csv file and have it read out all column names, then asks the users what you want for your x-axis and y-axis and plots that graph. The csv file format is:

```html
time(s),speed(mph),heading,bvoltage(v)
20,30,50,10
25,45,50,10
30,50,55,9
```

Here is my attempt at the code but I am missing a lot of information:

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
## names = where I will store the column names

white True:
    ## display names to user
    print ('Pick your x-axis')
    xaxis = input()
    print ('Pick your y-axis')
    yaxis1 = input()
    print('pick a 2nd y-axis or enter none')
    yaxis2 = input()
        if input()= 'none'
        break;
        else continue
    #plot xaxis vs yaxis vs 2nd yaxis
```

I understand the loop is not correct. I don't want anyone to correct me on that I will figure it out myself, however, I would like a way to access those values from the CSV file so that I can use it in that method.

Comment: Use the python library **pandas**. Create a **DataFrame** object using the method .read_csv().
DataFrame structures are very easy to use and their indexing is natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas` you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("yourFile.csv", delimiter=",")
```

and plot columns with names `ColName1`, `ColName2` against each other with:

```
data.plot(x='Col1', y='Col2')
```

If you have a first line in the csv file with the desired names of the columns, `pandas` will pick those automatically, otherwise you can play with the `header` argument of `read_csv`.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using/installing another module then **pandas** should do it.